# How can Install RVM in CentOS 5.5?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm

I followed this link to install RVM https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

and then gave command `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

I'm getting the following error:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 100   185  100   185    0     0    105      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
 curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
 error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
 More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

 curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). The default
 bundle is named curl-ca-bundle.crt; you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed 
 by a CA represented in  the bundle, the certificate verification probably
 failed due to a  problem with the certificate (it might be expired, 
 or the name might not match the domain name in the URL).
 If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

How can I solve this? Is there any better installation manual to install RVM in CentOS 5.5?

Comment: Try curl -k -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Comment: -1 as in the error text as copied in the question curl clearly explains 1) what happened and 2) explains how the problem can be solved.

Comment: Tried curl -k -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable   Still getting the same error

Comment: fvu, Can you tell me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run:

```
sudo curl -L http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

It will update your certificates (I have tested it on centos 5.6).